# Apple Push Notification Service Statistics(apns)

Tags: ios, statistics, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to find information about `Apple Push Notification` Service usage?
How many people are using, and how many people are declining them?
Or maybe, somebody already has this sort of information?

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not provide a lot of information about how many users actually accept/decline push notifications but you can get a good idea of what's going on by comparing the number of total installs and the number of valid push notification tokens you have ( I'm assuming that since you are interested in analytics you already have a Push server set up ) Push notification tokens are only generated if a user accepts.

If you need more information about the actual push notifications, you'll need to get your hands dirty and actually add tracking code in the application. If you're looking for something free try Google Analytics for iOS with Custom Event Tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events

Urban Airship also provides a pretty good analytics service, but you have to be using their push notification server: http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging#analyze