# Azure Notification Hub: What is Success and Failure Property in NotificationOutcome

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification

Am I understand correctly with these two properties?

The NotificationOutcome.Success: Return the number of success pushes to the target devices. Not the actual device who received the notification. Is the provider who received the message.

The NotificationOutcome.Failure: Return the number of failure, may be the installation failed for certain devices etc.

Are we able to check whether the notification get pushed to the APS or Firebase?

Comment: Just wanted to add by APS you mean APNs = (Apple Push Notification service) - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Success` and `Failure` Property in `NotificationOutcome` just mean the number of messages that were processed without an error or could not be processed. In order to get the detailed info about the PNS errors when sending the notification via Azure Notification Hubs, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer#self-diagnose-tips).

For getting statistics about how many devices received the notifications, you could refer to the following approaches:

- For FCM, you need to sign in to your Google Play Developer Console and leverage the [FCM Diagnostics and Statistics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) feature.
- For APNS, it seems that Apple does not provide the statistics about how many devices accept/decline the push notifications. You could refer to the similar [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924633/apple-push-notification-service-statisticsapns) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090059/push-notifications-delivered-to-apple-apns-server-but-device-received-nothing).